# Sphinx のインストールについて

Tags: python, sphinx

Sphinx のインストールをpipでしました．
ですが，sphinx-quickstartで始めようとしたところ，以下の様なエラーが出てしまいました．

```
user:~ $ sphinx-quickstart
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user/anaconda/bin/sphinx-quickstart", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Sphinx==1.2.3', 'console_scripts', 'sphinx-quickstart')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 552, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2671, in load_entry_point
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'sphinx-quickstart') not found
```

いまいち，何が問題になっているかよくわかりません．
どのように対処すればいいでしょうか，ご存知の方いらっしゃったらご教授ください．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく、元々Sphinxが入っていたか、入れ直したかで環境が壊れているのだと思います。
一度アンインストールしてからインストールしなおしてみてください。

```
$ pip uninstall sphinx
$ pip install sphinx
```

これでだめな場合、 `user/anaconda/bin/sphinx-*` を手動で削除してから、上記を行ってみてください。

補足ですが、エラーメッセージの内容は、「インストールされているはずのSphinx-1.2.3が見つからない」と読み取れます。Sphinx-1.2.3以外のバージョンがインストールされているため見つからないのだと思われます。

Comment: 再インストールしたところ，解決しました．
ありがとうございます．

Comment: @AkiraMatsui 解決したら対象の回答を「採用」してもらえると嬉しいです。こんな感じ http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: 見落としていていました，ごめんなさい．押させて頂きました．